# How to pass a particular index of char array to outtextxy() function's third parameter in c

Tags: c, graphics, turbo-c

I actually want to print every character of the text (every index of char array) with a delay; hence, I am trying to develop a custom function which takes x co-ordinate, y co-ordinate, x increment and y increment, delay and the pointer to the char array of text using `outtextxy` in Turbo C.

Here's my code:

```
void printing(int x, int y, int xinc, int yinc, int d, char word[50]){
    int i;
    int size = strlen(word);
    setcolor(LIGHTGREEN);
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        outtextxy(x,y,word[i]);
    }
    x += xinc;
    y += yinc;
    delay(d);
}
```

But this gives me an error every time:

> Type mismatch in parameter '__textstring' in call to 'outtextxy'

How can I solve this?

Comment: That's because the third argument of the function should be passed a pointer to a string and you are passing it a mere character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter of the `outtextxy` function must be a pointer to a nul-terminated character string (or `char` array), but you are passing a *single* character.

As a quick fix, you can just declare a 2-character array (one for the nul terminator) and copy your single `char` into that before each call:

```c
void printing(int x, int y, int xinc, int yinc, int d, char word[50])
{
    int i;
    int size = strlen(word);
    setcolor(LIGHTGREEN);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        char text[2] = { word[i], 0 }; // This character plus nul terminator
        outtextxy(x, y, text);  // Array "decays" to a pointer to first char
    }
    x += xinc;
    y += yinc;
    delay(d);
}
```

However, there *may* be a different function, such as `putcharxy(int x, int y, char c)`, in the Turbo-C graphics library that you can use, instead, to outpt a single character at the given coordinates. (I don't have access to that library, or any authoritative online documentation, although there doesn't appear to be such a function declared in [this source](https://fossies.org/dox/TurboC-dev/graphics_8h_source.html).)